# Переход на другую страницу с передачей данных через нажатие кнопки JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Возник вопрос, мне нужно перейти на другую страницу с передачей данных, вот что попробовал:

````
```
<form action="C:\Users\Alex23432\Desktop\Сайты\pomodoro timer2\index.html?seWork=1&miWork=2" target="_blank">
    <button onclick="GoOnclick()">Переход по ссылке</button>
</form>
```
````

На другую страницу попадаешь, но данные не передаются.
Что делать?
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать без формы. На первой странице достаточно такой ссылки:

```html
<a href="C:\Users\Alex23432\Desktop\Сайты\pomodoro timer2\index.html?seWork=1&miWork=2">Переход по ссылке</a>
```

На второй (принимающей) странице (допустим, хотим принять значения параметра **seWork**) должен быть такой JS-код:

```js
let result = location.search.substring(1).split("&")[0].split("=")[1];
console.log(result);
```

Это был старый дедовский способ, а можно так:

```js
let result = new URL(location.href).searchParams.get("seWork");
console.log(result);
```

Это новый дедовский способ.

Comment: Спасибо большое!